# LDAP - ldapmodify - add two attributes in one operation doesn't work

Tags: attributes, ldap, addition

I read this book : "Mastering OpenLDAP". It is an old book - 2007 - the version of Openldap is the 2.3 in this book.

I use Openldap 2.5 (Ubuntu 22.04).

It is written that I can add two attributes by using ldapmodify this way:

```
dn: uid=nicholas,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: description title
description: This is a test
title: Cartesian philosopher
```

**but when I try it, it doesn't work:**

```
thierry@thierry-VirtualBox:~$ ldapmodify -x -w secret -D 'cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com'
dn: uid=nicholas,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: description title
description: This is a test
title: Cartesian philosopher

ldapmodify: wrong attributeType at line 4, entry "uid=nicholas,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com"
```

**Although it works well if I add one attribute, and then another. Why ?**

```
thierry@thierry-VirtualBox:~$ ldapmodify -x -w secret -D 'cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com'
dn: uid=nicholas,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: description
description: This is a test

modifying entry "uid=nicholas,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com"

^C
```

```
thierry@thierry-VirtualBox:~$ ldapmodify -x -w secret -D 'cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com'
dn: uid=nicholas,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: title
title: Cartesian philosopher

modifying entry "uid=nicholas,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com"

^C
```

```
thierry@thierry-VirtualBox:~$ ldapsearch -x -w secret -D 'cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com' -LLL '(uid=nicholas)'
dn: uid=nicholas,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
cn: Nicholas Malebranche
sn: Malebranche
uid: nicholas
ou: Users
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
title: Cartesian philosopher
description: This is a test
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The manpage has [an example of making multiple changes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapmodify#:%7E:text=Examples,-Assuming%20that%20the):

```
dn: cn=Modify Me,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: mail
mail: modme@example.com
-
add: title
title: Grand Poobah
-
add: jpegPhoto
jpegPhoto:< file:///tmp/modme.jpeg
-
delete: description
-
```

So in your case, yours should look something like this:

```
dn: uid=nicholas,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: description
description: This is a test
-
add: title
title: Cartesian philosopher
-
```

Comment: Sorry for the presentation (I don't understand how it works).
Thank you.
I already know the possibility to use the dash. It works well.

In the book, it is written:
"If the modification is adding several attributes, rather than splitting the additions up
using dashes, you can group them together:
dn: uid=nicholas,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: description title
description: This is a test
title: Cartesian philosopher
Note that, in this case, the add line has two attribute names (description and
title), followed by both attributes."

Comment: If it doesn't work, then version 2.5 must not support that.

Comment: Or it's more likely that it's the version of ldapmodify that doesn't support it.

Comment: Ok, anyway I don't think I made something wrong. It is yes likely, as you said, not to be supported in my situation. I keep reading the book.
bye.